# SQLDataReader getOrdinal() results in IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, sql, unit-testing, ado.net

I've got a `System.IndexOutOfRangeException` at when calling `SqlDataReader.GetOrdinal()`

I know this happened because there is no such column in the stored procedure result set.

I know this maybe some Microsoft ado.net error. And this is like 1% in the cases. I'm not using express edition for SQL server.

Do you know how can I reproduce it? what should I do in C# so i can get that 1% in my testcases?

Comment: GetOrdinal throws the exception if you pass a column name that doesn't exists. It is so by design and thus it is your job to avoid this situation. Why do you try to read a column that doesn't exists?

Comment: The column name does exist but some how the getOrdinal on overloading crash in like 1% to 5% of the cases as I understand from other posts. And Until know with the tests I've made I could not get this error only in production